# Zend Framework 2 - Difference between ServiceManagerAwareInterface and ServiceLocatorAwareInterface

Tags: zend-framework2

Just learning ZF2, and I am a bit confused.  I have a general understanding of the ServiceManager, and understand how to add Services, as well as using ServiceManagerAwareInterface to be able to pull Services into a class.  However in my searching I have come across a ServiceLocatorAwareInterface.

Can someone tell me the difference between the two and what scenarios I would use each?

Comment: The answer below is a good one, the ServiceManager is a specific implementation of a ServiceLocator, you should use ServiceLocator related insterfaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ServiceManagerAwareInterface` was introduced to cover specific needs of MVC component, which required specific implementation of service locator. iirc this limitation was lifted and `ServiceManagerAwareInterface` unofficially considered deprecated.

As for you, you do not want to depend on specific implementation rather than on contract aka interface. Hence you should prefer `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`.

Comment: Does that mean that the Skeleton Application will no longer contain a ServiceManager instance?  And in module.config.php would I then configure "service_locator" rather than "service_manager" as well?

Comment: @Aaron Murray please avoid `ServiceManagerAwareInterface` if not strictly needed. If you require injection of a `ServiceManager` (specifically) then you probably have a flaw in your architecture.

Comment: @AaronMurray no, configuration will still be for `"service_manager"`. Don't worry about that

Comment: well I thought I had a general idea of ServiceManager ;) now I am more confused than when I started this question.  Back to the books.  @Ocramius catch me on #ZFTalk when you are around/not busy

Comment: @AaronMurray `ServiceManager` is just an implementation of a `ServiceLocatorInterface`. You don't care about how your `ServiceLocatorInterface` instance looks like: you just want one.

Comment: so anywhere I would put ServiceManagerAwareInterface I can just safely put ServiceLocatorAwareInterface (and I don't need to actually have an implementation of one?)

Comment: @AaronMurray exactly: trust the interface only